# Delete rows which contain certain text

Tags: r, dataframe, delete-row

I want to delete rows in the column "Keyword" which contains words including "advertising", "advertise", and "advertisement".

The data frame looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `dplyr::filter(df, !grepl("advertis", Keyword))`

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grep`

```
df2 <- df1[grep("\\badvert.*", df1$Keyword, invert=TRUE),]
```

If the three words are specific, as @Frank suggested, the pattern can be replaced by `"\\badvertis(ement|ing|e)\\b"`

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the comment.  I added the word boundary